# Send alerts as email using react.js

Tags: reactjs, email, react-fullstack

guys I’m newbie in full stack development. I’m stuck at a part where

1. I want to make multiple user to log onto my website(react) for alerts.
2. If they login and click on subscribe to alert I want to save there reg. number corresponding to their email id.
3. And save all those details in the DB, and after every 30 minutes I want to make an API call with their reg. number and based on the data received I want to sen alerts to the user on their emailid.

I’m using react.js as front end application. Can someone share their view how can this be achievable.

I'm not familiar with backend.

I would really appreciate the help.

Thank You

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

frontend is all for the ui of your website and react is a frontend framework. for those functionalities you may want to look into backend a little bit.

Comment: Yes, but how should i move forward?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).